# Linear Mapping on Complex Matrices

Tags: matrices, linear-transformations

I read in a textbook that says "...a general linear map of $d$ by $d$ complex matrices to $d$ by $d$ complex matrices is described by $d^4$ independent parameters..."
I am thinking shouldn't it be $2d^2$ independent parameters since the mapping must be $d$ by $d$ with two parameters for each entry (one for the real and one for the imaginary part)?

Comment: The parameters are complex.

Comment: In that case shouldn't it be $4d^2$? I mean I've already accounted for complex parameters... @saulspatz

Comment: No, the book is right.  See the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the book is right. If you have a vector space $V$ of dimension $n$, then the vector space of linear maps from $V$ to $V$ has dimension $n^2$. You can think about it in terms of matrices: a linear map from an $n$-dimensional space to an $n$-dimensional space can be expressed as an $n \times n$ matrix.

In this case, the complex $d \times d$ matrices form a space of dimension $n = d^2$. So, linear maps between this space and itself must have dimension $n^2 = d^4$.

Comment: I see what you mean. Thanks!